# syntax error in insert into mdb

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I write a string for `INSERT` to mdb file in c#, but error "syntax error in insert into statment" catched in code.
I test string directly in `Microsoft Access 2007` and query inserted with no error.

```
string qu = "INSERT INTO Reports ( docid, biopsy, normal, section, subsection, title, items, [text] ) VALUES (21, False, False, 'Recommendation', 'a', 'Injection', 'a', 'a');";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OleDbConnection con = Model.getDataConnection();

cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = qu;
con.Open();
try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("data error!\n" + ex.Message);
    return false;
}
```

---

The original string that shows the correct bracketing, prior to an unfortunate edit.

```
string qu = "INSERT INTO Reports ( docid, biopsy, normal, [section], subsection, title, items, [text] ) VALUES (21, False, False, 'Recommendation', '', 'Injection', '', '');";
```

Comment: I think the problem is the "empty" char. A char cannot be empty, but has a fixed size. Try using an empty string or '\0' for a null char.

Comment: I use ' ' and NULL but not answered!

Comment: Don´t use '' or NULL. Use \"\" (which is "") or '\0', which is the char value null, not the object.

Comment: No, in ms access my query is correct.

Comment: Do you know the internal workings of Access? It may very well be that certain characters are converted internally to prevent errors. Have you tried it in your code??

Comment: I test samples in code debugging and no answer.

Comment: I've created a test project, copied your code, created a test database and on my side it works like a charm, even with '' and using the same field names as you are...

Comment: I ran exactly that query against a test database and it works. I suspect that you have a different data type than you think on one of the fields.

Comment: Here : `string sql = "create table Reports ( docid counter primary key, biopsy yesno, normal yesno, [section] text, subsection text, title text, items text, [text] text );";` BTW `text` is just about one of the worst names you could pick for an Access field.

Comment: Could you also provide your connection string?

Comment: thanks, but my database image is
ID > AutoNumber,
docid > Number,
biopsy, normal > Yes/No,
section, subsection, title, items, text > Text

Comment: I have a function like for all my queries that get qu as parameter.  
i haven't any problem in other my queries! in select, update and insert.

Comment: You are sure it is the same database in both cases? You are not copying to the project folder?

Comment: problem is [section]!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Reports*, *section*, and *text* are all [reserved words](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).  Enclose them in brackets in your SQL statement.

```
INSERT INTO [Reports] (
    docid, biopsy, normal, [section], subsection, title, items, [text])
VALUES (
    21, False, False, 'Recommendation', 'a', 'Injection', 'a', 'a');
```

Comment: You have been misled by a bad edit. Note that two people had tested the query.